# A peculiar painting

Tags: pattern, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

I stopped by Carl Gauss's house for a cup of tea last week, and noticed this peculiar painting which he had hanging above his fireplace. I can't quite figure out what it means. Can anybody help me?

[image: Gauss's Painting]

Comment: Hm... looks like a chessboard, but I can't see any pattern in the doors - the only thing I see is the suns being arranged in the pattern of a knight's possible moves.

Comment: Added this to the [Fortnightly Challenge](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4698/fortnightly-topic-challenge-8-visual)

Comment: All I have figured out is that it is definitely not a [magic eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_Eye)

Comment: @Deusovi There is a pattern in the doors - just look them from the center formed by the suns... and extend the board at least from top, right and bottom ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given that

> Starting with a knight at F5 the suns are reachable in one move, the shoes in two, the trees in three and the doors in four.

Then

> Five would be a hive (in a [mnemonic peg system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnemonic_peg_system))

Comment: "sun, shoe, tree, door, ..." try listing them out loud.

Comment: @f'' guess that's what you mean? Still not an answer is it?

Comment: Yep! That's right.

Comment: Ah.  Okay.  I was thinking that, perhaps, since Carl Gauss was in the shoe business, for a while, that it was a reminder, in the morning, to put out the shoes, turn around the (wooden) open/closed sign, and unlock the door, for business. :)  I hope there's no beehives in that process, though.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated answer:**

> **Morning routine**
> At first, the knight reaches the sun (he starts as just "the [k]night"), beginning of his morning. Then, he puts his shoes on and proceeds out the door to... fight the good fight?

Going off of Beastly Gerbil's answer,

> The pictures are in circles around that one square. Maybe the sun is that square, and the suns are Mercury and the doors are Venus, and this is a representation of the center of our Solar System?

Comment: Very nice idea but how do you explain the trees and shoes?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Space between orbits? I considered maybe the shoes or trees could be Venus and the doors could be Earth, but those are also inside Mercury's orbit, if so. Also, there's no real sun... I was just going to comment on your answer because it didn't seem to fit perfectly, but I got nervous and thought "Oh no, it might be too different, etc. etc." Not really something to get anxious about, but that's generally the case.

Comment: I guess maybe... "It's art, so it doesn't have to be perfect, it just has to represent that thing to the artist"?

Comment: @SenderReagent I believe my answer is only a partial answer (At least I hope it is otherwise this is a very simple puzzle). I imagine that the pictures can be replaced by something, I just don't think its planets. Like I said though very nice idea

Comment: Ah, crap, I forgot about the trees. Meh... Well, I continue to feel this type of puzzle might not be my strong suit... but do I even have one of those?

Comment: @SendersReagent I like the updated answer, I just wish the trees fit in. Pretty close though.

Answer (score 1):

Each picture is part of a circumference of pictures of the same kind with the center of the circle around the 30th square, the picture of shoes in the center of the suns.

Comment: You're onto something... But what does it represent?

Comment: @knrumsey doors, shoes, trees and suns? :P